# .NET Core 1.1 Is it possible to use a powershell script with project.json scripts

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to use a powershell script as part of a precompile process.  In the project.json file there is a section where you can specify scripts at different levels during compilation, one of which is precompile. For ex:

```
"scripts": {
  "precompile": [
    "assemblyInfo.ps1"
  ]
}
```

When I do this and compile I get the following error:

```
The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
```

Is it not possible to do this?

Comment: did you ever figure this problem out?

Comment: @Jon49 it doesn't support powershell scripts, you could however use a batch script that then calls something else

Answer (score 0):

Per `ExoComp`

> it doesn't support powershell scripts, you could however use a batch script that then calls something else

I ended up just using a Node.js CLI script.